# How to configure Kibana to Elasticsearch Cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, kibana

If I have to point Kibana to an existing ElasticSearch Cluster which is secured with username and password. How do I do that, does it involve configuration of both Kibana and Elasticsearch? I got some information [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/setting-up-authentication.html), but still, it is not clear what would be the process. Can someone, please elaborate on steps which I need to take? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Kibana docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-server-properties.html) you simply need to make sure that the following two properties are also set in your `kibana.yml` config:

```
elasticsearch.username: <username>
elasticsearch.password: <password>
```

Comment: Thats true. Do I also have to make any configuration changes on Elasticsearch yml file?

Comment: According to your question, it sounds like your ES is already secured with username and password, right?

Comment: Then it should work without modifying anything in ES. Try it out.

Comment: No my question is whether do I have to do any configuration in ES config file?

Comment: Sorry, I took a shortcut, but that basically meant that nothing needed to be changed in the ES configuration, not in ES itself.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! I will try this and update if it works fine